# C# winapi mouse_event

Tags: c#, winapi

```
        static uint DOWN = 0x0002;
        static uint UP = 0x0004;    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo); 
        
        static void Click()
        {
            mouse_event(DOWN, 800, 800, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(UP, 800, 800, 0, 0);
        }
```

Why it  does not click on my coordinates 800 800, it clicks where my mouse is

Comment: i also think you need to specify `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) tells you how to use this API. We cannot help you, since we don't know what `DOWN` or `UP` are.

Comment: const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002; - DOWN
const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004; - UP

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62626388/edit) your question to include that information. Since you didn't tell the API to interpret your input as *absolute* values, it does what's [described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event): *"those parameters contain relative data: the change in position since the last reported position"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to click specified point instead of relative movement, the [`MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) flag is required. And in order for making the movement from current position to target position, the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` flag is required.

So the code will like this:

```
    static uint DOWN = 0x0002;
    static uint UP = 0x0004;
    static uint MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
    static uint MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    static void Click()
    {
        mouse_event(DOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 800, 800, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        mouse_event(UP | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 800, 800, 0, 0);
    }
```

And note:

> If `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` value is specified, `dx` and `dy` contain
> normalized absolute coordinates between `0` and 65,535. The event
> procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate
> `(0,0)` maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface,
> `(65535,65535)` maps onto the lower-right corner.

So if you want to click the specified pixel of the screen you can convert absolute coordinate to screen pixel like this:

```
    static int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
    static int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

    static void Click()
    {
        int sx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        int sy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

        int x = 800 * 65536 / sx;
        int y = 800 * 65536 / sy;

        mouse_event(DOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        mouse_event(UP | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
    }
```

**Note  `mouse_event` function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.**

Comment: You cannot use `SendInput` if the goal is to introduce a delay in between the individual calls to inject input. Also, someone has already implemented a [multiply-divide function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-muldiv). There's no reason to roll your own, and get it wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable Good suggestion! Thanks.