# How to perform mouse event in c#? where is the probleme here

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I'm trying do do three mousclicks in my c# programm.
I found this on the internet: https://forum.chip.de/discussion/1668318/visual-studio-c-2010-mausklick-simulieren

So I've tried this, but for me nothing is happening.

```
        private const UInt32 MouseEventLeftUp = 0x0004;
        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "mouse_event")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dx, UInt32 dy, UInt32 dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

And here the mousclicks i'm trying

```
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Vollbild");
                mouse_event(MouseEventLeftDown, 1700, 1138, 0, new System.IntPtr());
                mouse_event(MouseEventLeftUp, 1700, 1138, 0, new System.IntPtr());
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                // OEE
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " OEE");
                mouse_event(MouseEventLeftDown, 1470, 380, 0, new System.IntPtr());
                mouse_event(MouseEventLeftUp, 1470, 380, 0, new System.IntPtr());
                Thread.Sleep(15000);
                //Astronic
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Astronic");
                mouse_event(MouseEventLeftDown, 220, 370, 0, new System.IntPtr());
                mouse_event(MouseEventLeftUp, 220, 370, 0, new System.IntPtr());
```

Anyone have a idea where is the problem here

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626388/c-sharp-winapi-mouse-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to move mouse to the position of (1700, 1138) then click, try this instead:

```
 mouse_event(0x0001, 1700, 1138, 0, new IntPtr(0))
 mouse_event(MouseEventLeftDown, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr(0))
 mouse_event(MouseEventLeftUp, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr(0))
```

but these ain't moving the mouse to an absolute point (1700, 1138) on screen, instead it derived from the last mouse event proc position or the console top left by default (I guess?)

If you want to move the mouse to absolute position on screen, combine it with the flag *MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE* (0x8000) as following:

```
 mouse_event(0x8000 | 0x0001, (ushort.MaxValue / SCREEN_WIDTH) * 1700, (ushort.MaxValue / SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 1138, 0, new IntPtr(0));
 mouse_event(LEFT_DOWN, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr(0));
 mouse_event(LEFT_UP, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr(0));
```

Note that I multiplied it with *(ushort.MaxValue / SCREEN_WIDTH)*, *(ushort.MaxValue / SCREEN_HEIGHT)*, as explained in the **Remark** section in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot already. The click is be performed now. But the position looks different. I've got a programm where i can see the x and y of where my mouse is, but here with this methode now the x and y is much smaller then what my programm tells me... Do you know how to get the right coordinates?

Comment: yeah, I did a similar thing long ago, forgot to talk about the absolute coordinate kinda thing, Ive just fixed the answer, hope it do the thing xD